# Usercontrol equivalent in html5

Tags: angularjs, html, reactjs

I am trying to find the equivalent of .Net usercontrol in the html5 SPA world. Does `react` component fall under this or `angular` directives. I want to create self contained sections of page made of multiple rendering components put together (grid,chart etc) that talks to a socket. And I want to reuse those by pointing to a different data source.

An example would be a chart and a grid (with underlying data) together with a button to flip between chart and grid. How will I make this as one component that can be used multiple times in same application and also shared to different applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can use Reactjs or Angularjs, I would recommend Reactjs in case if the sections' state are changing many times, in reactjs every component have a state, Reactjs knows when to re-render the component because it is able to observe when this data changes. Dirty checking is slow regarding the reactjs.

In other word Reactjs can give you much better performance, but note that Reactjs is only for the UI, no routing or other like in Angularjs.

I hope that helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've done this exact thing with a simple combination of JS objects, jQuery and Handlebars. No need for Angular et al if you don't want them (and nothing wrong with them if you do). I've defined my components as JS Objects:

```
/**
 * A data grid.
 */
function Grid(columns, $container) {
    this.columns = $.extend([], columns);
    ...
    this.render($container);
}

/**
 * Render the grid into a container.
 * @private
 */
Grid.prototype.render = function($container) {
```

Rendering the view is done with Handlebars:

```
<div class="grid">

    <header>
            <div class="label">
                {{#each columns}}<div data-id="{{id}}" data-index="{{@index}}" style="width:{{boxWidth}}px">{{name}}</div><nav></nav>{{/each}}
            </div>
```

The Model is obtained by ajax calls:

```
/**
 * Handle a grid filter change.
 * @private
 */
MasterCompanyList.prototype.onFilter = function(e, filter) {
    App.loading.start();
    App.ajax({
        url: 'ws/admin/mcl',
        data: filter.filter,
        context: this,
        success: function(json) {
            this.grid.setData(json);
            App.loading.done();
        }
    });
};
```

All at a simpler level than Angular etc (I've used Angular commercially for a few years), but I find this KISS approach gets me where I need to be without having to rely on a heavier framework - and if I want to manipulate something jQuery styles then off I go.

Answer (score -1):

Angular and React can do this, but React is based on a component design, so it would be perfect for what you're trying to achieve.